# Why does the number of parameters differ in each layer when each layer is defined the exact same way

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, tensorflow, models, dense-layers

```
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

layers = keras.layers
N_train = 10 ** 4  # number of training samples
# Note: "[:, np.newaxis]" reshapes array to (N,1) as required by our DNN (we input one feature per sample)
xtrain = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, N_train)[:, np.newaxis]
ytrain = some_complicated_function(xtrain) + np.random.randn(xtrain.shape[0])  # train data includes some noise 

# Each xtrain element is added with each and every randomizing element

nb_nodes = 2
nb_layers = 2
activation = "ReLU" # insert your choice of activation funciton
reg_strategy = "L1"# define your regularization strategy - use L1 and L2 regularization

model = keras.models.Sequential(name="1Dfit")
model.add(layers.Dense(nb_nodes, activation=activation, kernel_regularizer=reg_strategy, input_dim=xtrain.shape[1]))  # first layer

# insert your code for for creating additional layers 


model.add(layers.Dense(nb_nodes, activation=activation, kernel_regularizer=reg_strategy, input_dim=xtrain.shape[1]))  # second layer

model.add(layers.Dense(1))  # final layer

print(model.summary())
```

The output of this code is

Model: "1Dfit"

---

## Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #

dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 4

dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 6

dense_7 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 3

=================================================================
Total params: 13 (52.00 Byte)
Trainable params: 13 (52.00 Byte)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)

---

The number of nodes is 2 in each layer but the parameters are different. What am I missing and what do the number of parameters depend on?

Answer (score 1):

A dense layer is a function that maps an input $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{in}$ onto an output $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{out}$. This is implemented as a matrix multiplication, and to make the above computation work, the matrix is an $in \times out$-Matrix and has therefore $in \cdot out$ many parameters. If you use a dense layer with bias (like in your case), there will be a vector $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{out}$ added to the output, which increases the number of parameters of the layer to $in \times out + out$.

In your case: You have a 1-dimensional input and apply a layer with two output neurons, you get $1 \cdot 2 + 2 = 4$ parameters in the first layer. The subsequent layer (also 2 neurons) will have $2 \cdot 2 + 2 = 6$ parameters. And the last layer has $2 \cdot 1 + 1 = 3$ parameters.